# Is there a way to remove white lines space from my UICollectionView?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am having issue removing these white lines (see image bellow).

Here is my issue:
[White Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trXNr.jpg)

My code parts: (in my ViewController)

```swift
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/5, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/5)
```

```swift
extension TestVC: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellres.count
    }
  
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Cells.identifier, for: indexPath) as! Cells
        cell.configure(with: cellres[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}


extension TestVC: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
}
```

-I am using a xib file for my cells.

-Those white lines are not borders of my cell, because every number is a different cell (25 in total).

I have no idea where they are coming from and tried many things in the xib file check options and in my storyboards options as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to give minimum line spacing.

```
extension TestVC:UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the cell background and/or collectionView background colors to clear.

Comment: That's pretty much brushing it under the rug and doesn't fix anything. This site is literally only good for down voting new users. Once they don't know the answer to your question, somehow the user's get mad and down vote your question. This site is NOT welcoming for new users.

Comment: Hey Iaso, I totally understand the frustration. I have it myself. I'm not sure how setting the cell background color is brushing off the issue. It's just one of the many options you can choose to solve your problem. - Although after looking at your photo again, it looks like maybe the best course for this type of solution would actually be to set the background to the cell background.

Comment: I agree changing the backgrounds to same color fixes the issue if the cell/collectionview remain the same color. However my cells have different image backgrounds and opacity and still can see those lines (which are coming from the collectionview background). :/